# Pass from child window to parent window

Tags: c#, wpf, parent-child

I would like to ask,

I have a window called `MainWindow` and another one called `ImportForm`.
In the `MainWindow` i call

```
private void generate_Window(int num_chart) 
{ 
    Window ownedWindow = new ImportForm(num_chart); 
    ownedWindow.Owner = this;      
    ownedWindow.Show(); 
}
```

In the child window i make some stuff and i produce some variables. like var1,var2,var3.

I want when the child window close to return `var1`,`var2`,`var3` to the `MainWindow` and call one function let's say `import_chart(var1, var2, var3)`..

Any help will be apretiated.
Thanks

Comment: You could try creating an event and putting such variables inside it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like an awkward design choice. Anyways, here is how you can do it:

MainWindow.cs:

```
private void generate_Window(int num_chart)
{
    Window ownedWindow = new ImportForm(num_chart, import_chart); 
    ownedWindow.Owner = this; 
    ownedWindow.Show();
}

private void import_chart(int n, string s, bool b)
{
    //Do something
}
```

ImportForm.cs:

```
private Action<int, string, bool> callback;
public ImportForm(int num_chart, Action<int, string, bool> action)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Closed += ImportForm_Closed;
    callback = action;
}

private void ImportForm_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    callback(0, "Test", false);
}
```

Just change the Action to the parameter types you need (and adjust ImportForm_Closed(...) to use them as well).

If anything is unclear, let me know.

Comment: Yes it is really helpful... Thanks a lot... I owe you... Your answer  was really time saver..

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an event to your ImportForm "ImportFinished" where you pass in your values as the eventargs. This event is fired in the Close or Closing event of the ImportForm and handled in your MainWindow. 
You could also show the ImportForm as a Modal dialog and read the values when the ShowDialog method returns.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to make `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` instance variables that are visible in the scope of the parent (e.g. make them `public`), and then in the `MainWindow`, attach to the `Closed` event, and read the variables from `(ImportForm)sender`.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example from my own code. It's generic and obvious enough that I can share it here.

I've done something along these lines.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Show an InputBox similar to the pre-.NET InputBox functionality. Returns the original value when Cancel was pressed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="OriginalValue">Pre-populated value in the input box</param>
    /// <param name="PromptText">Prompt text displayed on the form</param>
    /// <param name="Caption">Window caption</param>
    /// <returns>InputBoxResult structure containing both the DialogResult and the input text. Warning: The input text will always be returned regardless of the DialogResult, so don't use it if the DialogResult is Cancel.</returns>
    public static InputBoxResult Show(string OriginalValue = "", string PromptText = "", string Caption = "") {
        InputBox form = new InputBox {
           Text = Caption,
            lblPrompt = {Text = PromptText}, 
            txtInput = {Text = OriginalValue}
        };

        InputBoxResult res = new InputBoxResult();
        res.Result = form.ShowDialog();
        res.Input = form.txtInput.Text;

        return res;
    }
```

I created a class called InputBoxResult like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the results from an InputBox.Show call, including the DialogResult
    /// and the input data. Note that the input data is always populated with the
    /// user-entered data regardless of the DialogResult - this is inconsistent with
    /// the old InputBox behavior and may change in the future.
    /// </summary>
    public struct InputBoxResult {
        /// <summary>
        /// Describes the way the dialog was resolved (OK / Cancel)
        /// </summary>
        public DialogResult Result { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// User-entered text
        /// </summary>
        public string Input { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Translate this result into a string for easy debugging
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override string ToString() {
            return "Result: " + Result.ToString() +
                "\r\nInput: " + Input.ToString();
        }
    }
```